# Добавления массива структур в класс

Tags: c++, qt

Сделал вот так

```
#ifndef SENSORMANAGER_H
#define SENSORMANAGER_H
#include <QObject>

class SensorManager : public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT
private:
struct Bal{
unsigned short int Voltage;
unsigned short int index;
};
Bal massifVoltageAndIndex[247];

public:
explicit SensorManager(QObject *parent = 0);
public slots:
void slotAutoModeBalancer(int numberBalanser);
};
#endif // SENSORMANAGER_H
```

При обращение

```
void SensorManager::slotAutoModeBalancer(int numberBalanser)
{
massifVoltageAndIndex.Voltage[0] = 1;
}
```

Получаю ошибку 
 error: request for member ‘Voltage’ in ‘((SensorManager*)this)->SensorManager::massifVoltageAndIndex’, which is of non-class type ‘SensorManager::Bal [247]’
  massifVoltageAndIndex.Voltage[0] = 1;
Что не так ?

Comment: massifVoltageAndIndex это массив структур Bal

вызов должен выглядеть как - то так 
massifVoltageAndIndex[0].Voltage = 1;

Comment: Понял сам дурак.

Comment: если поле index  структуры Bal не несет дополнительного смысла, а используется только для обращения к определнному значению, логичнее использовать QVector<int> voltage{247};

voltage[index] = value;